# How can I execute PHP code from the command line?

Tags: php, linux, function, shell, command-line

I would like to execute a single PHP statement like `if(function_exists("my_func")) echo 'function exists';` directly with the command line without having to use a separate PHP file.

How is it possible?

Comment: doing function_exists() without using any other files containing user defined function  isn't going to be much good, except for testing the PHP version, which you can find out in other ways. What function do you want to test for?

Comment: I'm looking for testing this function: sg_load()

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is to find out if the sourceguardian php extension is enabled?

Comment: then phpinfo() should tell you.

Answer (score 307, accepted):

**If you're going to do PHP in the command line, I recommend you install [phpsh, a decent PHP shell](http://www.phpsh.org/).** It's a lot more fun.

Anyway, the `php` command offers **two switches to execute code from the command line**:

```
-r <code>        Run PHP <code> without using script tags <?..?>
-R <code>        Run PHP <code> for every input line
```

You can use `php`'s **-r switch** as such:

```
php -r 'echo function_exists("foo") ? "yes" : "no";'
```

The above PHP command above should **output** `no` and **returns** `0` as you can see:

```
>>> php -r 'echo function_exists("foo") ? "yes" : "no";'
no
>>> echo $? # print the return value of the previous command
0
```

Another funny switch is **php -a**:

```
-a               Run as interactive shell
```

It's **sort of lame compared to [phpsh](http://www.phpsh.org/)**, but if you don't want to install [the awesome interactive shell for PHP made by Facebook to get tab completion, history, and so on](http://www.phpsh.org/), then **use -a as such**:

```
>>> php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo function_exists("foo") ? "yes" : "no";
no
```

**If it doesn't work** on your box like on my box**es** (**tested** on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) and [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux)), then **probably your PHP setup is fuzzy or broken**. If you run this command:

```
php -i | grep 'API'
```

You **should** see:

```
Server API => Command Line Interface
```

**If you don't**, this means that **maybe another command will provides the CLI SAPI**. Try php-cli; maybe it's a package or a command available in your OS.

**If you do** see that your `php` command uses the CLI (command-line interface) SAPI (Server API), then run `php -h | grep code` to **find out which crazy switch - as this hasn't changed for year-** allows to run code in your version/setup.

Another couple of examples, just to make sure it works on my boxes:

```
>>> php -r 'echo function_exists("sg_load") ? "yes" : "no";'
no
>>> php -r 'echo function_exists("print_r") ? "yes" : "no";'
yes
```

Also, note that it is possible that an extension is loaded in the CLI and not in the CGI or Apache SAPI. **It is likely that several PHP SAPIs use different php.ini files**, e.g., `/etc/php/cli/php.ini` vs. `/etc/php/cgi/php.ini` vs. `/etc/php/apache/php.ini` on a [Gentoo Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentoo_Linux) box. Find out which ini file is used with `php -i | grep ini`.

Comment: Maybe your php setup is broken. I updated my answer including hints to figure it out.

Comment: Added a note about php -a which might be useful to you.

Comment: Note that phpsh is no longer maintained by its author (Facebook) and someone on the Google Groups page [said in 2012 that "phpsh isn't really supported or useful any more"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/phpsh/not$20useful/phpsh/uWkee9cdcmY). You might look into the [Boris REPL](https://github.com/borisrepl/boris) for an improved php console.

Comment: simplest way is to  `php -a` I have added a picture and written an answer below

Comment: The single quotes for the "-r" lines would not work on Windows(?).

Answer (score 13):

[Using PHP from the command line](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)

Use `"` instead of `'` on Windows when using the CLI version with `-r`:

#### Correct

```
php -r "echo 1;"
```

#### Incorrect

```
php -r 'echo 1;'
```

```
  PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''echo' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting end of file in Command line code on line 1
```

Don't forget the semicolon to close the line (otherwise, the result is *"PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ';' or ',' in Command line code on line 1"*).

Answer (score 5):

To run a PHP shell through a Windows command:

```
php -a
```

It will open the below PHP shell in Windows, where I was testing a simple `square_val()` function:

```
function square_val($num, $pow){
  return $num**$pow;
}
```

The above code was tested.

To test that the above code works, use `echo square_val(4, 2);` and then `echo square_val(4, 0.5);`.

[image: php-shell-command-line]

Answer (score 4):

On the command line:

```
php -i | grep sourceguardian
```

If it's there, then you'll get some text. If not, you won't get a thing.

Comment: Either I'm blind or this answer has nothing to do with the question. How this answer is supposed to answer question asking "_How to run PHP code directly from command line, without saving PHP code into `.php` file?_"?

Comment: @trejder For a moment there I wondered if I'd answered the wrong question, but then I looked at the edit history and comments. This answers what the OP appeared to really need: finding out whether a particular PHP extension was loaded. The question has since been rephrased, so it does not fit so well now.

Comment: It is valid for PHP code to be in a file.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
 echo '<?php if(function_exists("my_func")) echo "function exists"; ' | php
```

The short tag "*< ?=*" can be helpful too:

```
 echo '<?= function_exists("foo") ? "yes" : "no";' | php
 echo '<?= 8+7+9 ;' | php
```

The closing tag "?>" is optional, but don't forget the final ";"!

Comment: This seems to be more trouble than the 7 year old accepted answer. Using `php -r` you don't need to worry about opening PHP tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Laravel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel), you can use `php artisan tinker` to get an amazing interactive shell to interact with your Laravel app. However, Tinker works with "Psysh" under the hood which is [a popular](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh) PHP REPL and **you can use it even if you're not using Laravel** (bare PHP):

```
// Bare PHP:
>>> preg_match("/hell/", "hello");
=> 1

// Laravel Stuff:
>>> Str::slug("How to get the job done?!!?!", "_");
=> "how_to_get_the_job_done"
```

One great feature I really like about [Psysh](https://psysh.org/) is that it provides a quick way for directly looking up the PHP documentation from the command line. To get it to work, you only have to take the following simple steps:

```
apt install php-sqlite3
```

And then get the required PHP documentation database and move it to the proper location:

```
wget http://psysh.org/manual/en/php_manual.sqlite
mkdir -p /usr/local/share/psysh/ && mv php_manual.sqlite /usr/local/share/psysh/
```

Now for instance:

[image]