# Is there any way to call PHP file from VBScript?

Tags: php, vbscript

I have tried this.
Sample `hello.php` file:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Sample `ex.vbs` VBScript file:

```vb
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "D:\Example\hello.php", 0
```

When I executed VBScript in command prompt output is not displaying.

Comment: You can  run `php` and pass parameters (similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520090/how-to-execute-php-code-from-the-command-line), but looking at the body of the post you likely interesting in rendering of web page rather than just running script. Please clarify your question (and show what ways of running php you've already found in addition to one shown)

Comment: I am executing VBScript file which calls PHP file. I am executing in command prompt like, path\cscript ex.vbs. It is not showing any error. But i should get output as Hello World.